# How to convert json to csv after using an API export python

Tags: python, json, pandas, csv

I used an API data export and ended up with this python dictionary/json format and get this:

```
json_data = json.loads(response.text)

[{'key': [‘a’, ‘b’, ‘c’],
  'value': 1},
 {'key': [‘d’,
   ‘e’,
   ‘f’],
  'value': 2},
 {'key': [‘g’,
   ‘h,
   ‘i’],
  'value': 3},
.....
```

I have tried using pandas and df = pd.read_json and then df.to_csv but get a dataframe with a key and value column with the key array all bunched together then have to use str.strip and format all of the columns manually. I just want to convert this into a csv where key[0], key[1], key[2] as well as the values are all separate columns like this:

```
column 1 | column 2 | column 3 | column 4 |
-------------------------------------------
   a     |    b     |     c    |     1    |
-------------------------------------------
   d     |    e     |     f    |     2    |
```

Comment: can you be more specific what you want the output to be? Ie: mock up a resulting dataframe...

Comment: I edited the question to include an example of the dataframe that I would like! Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it's always three elements in the list and the value you can do the following. But if there's a variable number of elements you'll have to come up with a more robust solution. Search the site for splitting lists to columns.

```
d = [{'key': ['a', 'b', 'c'],
  'value': 1},
 {'key': ['d',
   'e',
   'f'],
  'value': 2},
 {'key': ['g',
   'h',
   'i'],
  'value': 3}]

df = pd.DataFrame(d)
df1 = pd.DataFrame(df["key"].to_list(), columns=['key1', 'key2', 'key3'])
df1['value'] = df['value']
```

Output:

```
In [49]: df1
Out[49]:
  key1 key2 key3  value
0    a    b    c      1
1    d    e    f      2
2    g    h    i      3
```